# When does running Jython on a .py file generate a .class file?

Tags: python, jython, jvm-languages

I just started playing with Jython, and sometimes running jython on a .py file generates a .class file, but this doesn't always happen.

At first I thought the trigger was that you had to define a Python class inside the .py file, but evidently a .class file is not always generated even then.

What is the mechanism that triggers the class file?

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't look like that's the case -- there are several import statements in there.

Comment: Oh, ok. Evidently that does generate the .class file. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With regular Python, `.pyc` files are generated when you `import` a module but not when it's the `__main__` module.

It is the same with Jython -- `.class` files are generated when you `import` a Jython module.

You can use `jythonc` to manually compile a module.

Comment: There is no jythonc in Jython 2.5 though.